# How can I create a custom ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to create a custom ActionBar using setCustomView, however when the app loads, the default ActionBar is loaded before the custom view and the options (menu items) are added to the actionbar automatically.

I need to create an ActionBar like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homes.rentals

How can I do this?

UPDATE:

I'm using the ActionBar AppCompat support library.

Comment: maybe you could just write your own style for defualt actionbar?

Comment: As far as I know and searched for, there is no style option to center the actionbar title, remove the icon, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about then you make custom layout xml how ever you want it to look like and then something like:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);

actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

EDIT: 
to remove your icon from ActionBar, in Java, call `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)` and `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` on your ActionBar.

Comment: Is it different from doing this way?
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);

Comment: well its should be same, but you could test it :)

Comment: Actually, both code work, however Android displays the default actionbar before loading the custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SherlockActionBar` library that support very low `API` Starting from `API-7`. This library allow you to add customActionBar UI icons and handle its actions.

Download the `SherlockActionBar` from this [link](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

And use this simple [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html) to know how to use it.

Comment: I'm using the AppCompat support library.

Comment: Try `Sharlock` it is more simple in usage and in integrating.